# JSOM Error: unable to get property 'apply'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom

I get an error after attempting to update an item SharePoint 2013.  This one is a bit of a challenge since it's referencing a different file.

```
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Document Approval');
var oListItem = oList.getItemById(promise.responseJSON.d.results[0].ID);

oListItem.set_item('Role Status', roleStatus); 
oListItem.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
 Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddSucceeded),
 Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddFailed)
);
```

I get the folllowing error that says **"SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference.  File: ScriptResource.axd, Line 5, Column: 298"**

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you reference the wrong function in your `executeQueryAsync`. Instead of using `Function.createDelegate` just pass the reference to your functions:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onAddSucceeded, onAddFailed);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thank you!  Any more explanation of why 'Function.createDelegate' did not work?

Comment: You referenced `this.onAddSucceeded` in `Function.createDelegate`. I bet if you put `console.log(this.onAddSucceeded)` it will print `undefined`. In other words, you've tried to set undefined function as your success \ failure handler.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. I'm assuming it's also because those function are not part of the 'clientContext' object?

Comment: technically they're not part of `this`. however, I don't know what is `this` in your application, because you haven't provided full code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

As compared from the [Microsoft Document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v%3Doffice.14))

```
oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title'); // both the parameters of set_item function accepts string where the first string parameter denotes the field name and the second string parameter denotes the value of the item to be set.
```

Your code:

```
oListItem.set_item('Role Status', roleStatus);  // make sure roleStatus is a string
```

There's already an answer to this issue in the following post [Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93901/getting-list-using-javascript-error-unable-to-get-property-apply-of-undefine)

Comment: roleStatus is not the problem.  It's a variable that grabs different values based on the item selected.  It's dynamic, so it works fine.  Thanks though.